# Node.jsでのrequireについて

Tags: node.js

test.js、file.jsがあったとして、test.jsに下のような記述をしたとします。

```js
// test.js
var hoge = true;
require('./file');
```

このときfile.js内からhogeを参照する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 表題ですが、解決しました。
`var hoge = true;`のところを
`global.hoge = true;`にしました。
ただ、あまり推奨されていない方法かもしれません。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 0):

`var hoge = true;` のところを `global.hoge = true;` に変更することで解決しました。

ただ、あまり推奨されていない方法かもしれません。

---

*この投稿は [@user26654 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40284/node-js%e3%81%a7%e3%81%aerequire%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment40958_40284) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*